# Is there a better way to programatically get the networking parameters from Linux OS?

Tags: networking, programming, ip, ifconfig

I am writing some scripts which need to programatically get a lot of networking parameters from Linux OS.

For example, the `names of all network interfaces, ip address, netmask, MAC address`. For wireless interface, I may also need to get the `bit rate, frequency, operating mode, transmit power, signal level, noise level`, etc.

Currently, I am using normal text progressing and regular expression to parse the output of Linux command line tools like `ifconfig, ip, route, iw and iwconfig`. One of the problems of this method is that sometimes the output will be different from what we have expected. It is difficult to predict all possible output format for all possible scenarios.

Is there a better way to programatically get the networking parameters from Linux OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the names of all the defined network interfaces, I'd just look at the contents of the `/sys/class/net` directory.

For the rest, it depends what you mean by "Linux OS". If you are referring to current desktop versions of Ubuntu, then the `nmcli` command-line utility seems to provide a lot of the functionality that you are looking for e.g.

```
$ nmcli --terse --fields FREQ,RATE,SIGNAL dev wifi list bssid XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
5220 MHz:54 MB/s:70

$ nmcli --terse --fields IP4 dev list iface wlan0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:ip = 192.168.1.16/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:192.168.1.1
```

If that does not provide the fine control that you need, you could roll your own by interfacing to DBUS either using the command-line `dbus-send` and/or `dbus-monitor` tools or the C or python DBUS API's - the documentation is a bit thin but there are one or two helpful tutorials for example [Dbus Tutorial - Fun with Network Manager](http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.ca/2012/09/dbus-tutorial-fun-with-network-manager.html)

Answer (score 1):

this may help (providing you do not mind python):

http://it-ebooks.info/book/3515/

page 66 (79)

since this recipe rely on c sys-calls you may be much better off writing a module in C.

Comment: http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/enumerating-network-interfaces-on-linux.html